# Keyboard shorcut for Nightlight Gnome 3.24 Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, 17.04, gnome-shell

I would like to be able to activate and deactivate the night light feature in Gnome 3.24 with a keyboard command.

Since I cant find any information on the bash command, my only solution is to ask the internet for some assistance.

I'm currently running the ubuntu 17.94 with a Gnome 3.24 shell.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are still wanting to know, this command worked for me,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled true
```

Changing 'true' to 'false' turns it off. Worked it out after seeing this: https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/6cvlb6/how_to_configure_night_light_in_gnome_324x/

Comment: Probably we can create [custom shortcut](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en) with this command :)

Comment: I've put this into a simple [script](https://gist.github.com/kapad/bdbf5df735690afd8cd36225becf7304) that you can link to a custom keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 5):

Chiming in for Ubuntu 18.04 here-- I used the standard keyboard shortcut and was able to use the following command:

```bsh
bash -c "if [[ $(gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled) == "true" ]]; then gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled false; else gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled true; fi"
```

It's not super readable but it works.  It's based on the [script](https://gist.github.com/kapad/bdbf5df735690afd8cd36225becf7304) that @kapad wrote up on his or her Github; I simply shortened it to a one-liner so you could paste it right in.  Now <kbd>F7</kbd> is toggling the nightlight on my system!

Comment: Wow, that was an easy solution! Works on Pop!_OS 21.04, too.

Answer (score 4):

Are you still interested in this? If so, you can follow this guide

1. Using script from @[kapad](https://askubuntu.com/users/59090/kapad) - [script](https://gist.github.com/kapad/bdbf5df735690afd8cd36225becf7304), make file under `~/.local/share/myscript` (you can use any folder name) with name `togglens` without any file extension
2. Open terminal in that folder, and `chmod +x togglens` to make it executable
3. Now create symlink for the file to `/usr/local/bin` using code `sudo ln -s ~/.local/share/myscript/togglens /usr/local/bin/togglens`
4. Now you can set the keyboard shortcut to gnome setting using any combination you like, just put `togglens` in the command section.

Answer (score 0):

I also fixed the Disable Until Tomorrow nightlight activation problem. Here it is:

```
BUS_NAME="org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color"
OBJECT_PATH="/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Color"

stop_disable_until_tomorrow() {
   dbus-send --session --dest=$BUS_NAME --print-reply $OBJECT_PATH  org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set string:$BUS_NAME string:DisabledUntilTomorrow variant:boolean:false >> /dev/null 2>&1
}
stop_disable_until_tomorrow
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution so far in my opinion is here https://dev.to/shafiemoji/gnome-night-light-keyboard-shortcut-3mgo

Use the Settings > Keyboard panel to assign a custom keyboard shortcut to:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled true
```

and one to

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled false
```

No need for executable scripts anywhere.